# How to find the sum of a power series without knowing the actual power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

How do I find the sum of this series?
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n}{(n+1)2^{n-1}} $$
The approach I wanted to use is to find a power series that can become this number series for a certain value of $x$.
The problem I encountered is that I am not sure how to extract that $x$.
Here is what I tried but I am not sure if this is even valid:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n}{(n+1)2^{n-1}} = 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n}{(n+1)2^{n}} => 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n}{(n+1)} \frac{1}{2^n} => 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n}{(n+1)}x^n $$
Where $x=\frac{1}{2}$

Is what I have done so far correct and if it is what should I do next?

Comment: You can write $(-1)^{n-1}nx^n=(1-(n+1))(-x)^n$. Then: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n}{n+1}\,x^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n+1}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-x)^n$$
(because both sums converge).

Comment: That makes sense. Does that mean that what I did so far is correct? The splitting up and extraction of $2$ and turning $x = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @NikolaJ It is correct. Note that you can start the summations at $n=0$ in nejimban's comment which makes the identification of those powers series easier.

Comment: Whatever I do I can't find sum of that first (split) series.

Comment: According to WA the sum is equal to $4 \left( \ln \frac{3}{2} - \frac{1}{3} \right)$

Comment: @Christian yes, I am aware of that, but I am not able to reproduce that result using anything I know.

Comment: @NikolaJ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series